# What is the most efficient way to increase the frequency of a waveform?

Tags: power-supply, ac, components, appliances

More specifically, I have an electric induction kettle. From what I understand, it heats the water by sending a high frequency (voltage?) signal around ~24kHz. This high frequency signal causes a rapidly changing magnetic field that induces many eddy currents into the material. The bottom of the pot becomes hot and heats the water through conduction. My question is, how is a high frequency signal created from the 120V AC current in the wall in such a small area (the induction device is roughly the size of a large hand).

Comment: Google "Induction hob teardown" (w/o the quotes) for more information, images, videos.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: semiconductor switches switching on and off extremely rapidly.

A longer answer will have to wait for either someone else, or the morning.